# Only part of image is rendered

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, resolution

So I am trying to render an image with a resolution of 5000px X 2500px
(I have cleared render region) But it still only renders a part of the image (see screenshot) Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Render engine : Cycles

[image]

Comment: Have you cleared the render region in the view you were in when defining it?

Comment: What do you mean? I am in camera view and then selected under view > view regions > clear render region. Or is that wrong?

Comment: ok, it was just to be sure you cleared it in the camera view.

Comment: ah thnx no I was hoping it was that

Comment: is this finished render in F12(render image) or viewport? Or is it running and not finished render?

Comment: The screenshot is just started but I finshed it yesterday and it was when finished the same .

Comment: Whe I try to render it smaller it does show orange borders, but I just cannot find where to undo that)

Comment: Go to **Render settings** (right panel), scroll down and find **Performance** and under **Memory** do you have **Use Tiling** checked? If yes, it means that it renders in default tiles 2048*2048, your image is 5000*2500 which means that it renders your image in 6 tiles, try to turn it off if it will render whole image

Comment: yes! thats it THANKS! :)

Comment: keep in mind that those tiles have purpose, it is generally known that if you render with CPU it is better to use many small tiles and if you are using GPU you want to render image whole or in a few big tiles, many people don't know about this possibility in settings and figure it only if they render something bigger than 2048*2048